# Is it possible to create templates for Ionic like Ignite does for React Native?

Tags: ionic-framework, react-native, jhipster

I'm looking to create an Ionic app generator for JHipster similar to [ignite-jhipster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignite-jhipster). Is it possible to do something like this for Ionic, or would it be best to implement this as a JHipster module?